# Can't access the `rawBytes` public member in the `BarCode`class

Tags: java, android, barcode

To use the content of a `BarCode`, I want to access to it's raw value. If I use the `rawValue` member, the compilation ends successfully, but when I try with the `rawBytes` member, the compiler stops with an error indicating it can't find the `rawBytes`symbol...

As both members are declared `public`, according to the Android documentation, I don't understand why I can use one and not the other.

Any explanation?

How I import the `BarCode`class : `import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;`

How I access both members :

```java
Barcode b=new Barcode();
String s=b.rawValue;
byte [] tab=b.rawBytes;
```

The `rawBytes` word is displayed in red in the editor.

Comment: Either the documentation is lying or the compiler is lying (or you're not doing what you think you're doing).

Comment: How do you access it?

Comment: Can you show us, what BarCode-class you use?
Just show us the import, a link or something else.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you talking about?

Comment: @Kayaman the compiler never lies.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode.html#rawBytes) is the documentation. It indeed exposes the `rawBytes` field. Are you sure you are using the latest version?

Comment: I don't see any `rawBytes` field in the `Barcode` class from `play-services-vision:18.0.0`. Perhaps it was added in 19.0.0(?). Which version are you using?

Comment: The only library I'm using is "play-service". Was using version 7.8. Changed to 11.0.4 without improvement.

Comment: `play-services:11.0.4` was released in june 2017. Is there any reason why you're using such an old version?

Comment: That's the highest version I can choose in the project structures dependencies. My SDK is apparently up-to-date (Google play service is announced as installed in version 49).

Comment: Can't you just add a newer version as a dependency in your gradle script? (see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: Manually adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'` in the `Dependancies` of the `build.gradle` file solved the problem. Thanks for your help!